# JAWS reads "link" between every line of text in a table cell

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I am facing issue while reading multiple lines in a single table cell. I am using Insert+Shift followed by key T to move to the table layer. After this, I am using down arrow key to read the table contents. Once it comes to the cell which has multiple

tags, it reads in this manner:
content of line1, "link", "content of line2".

In the following example it reads "Alfreds Futterkiste, link, Nice to test".

How can I get rid of the text "link" in between and make the text "Nice to test" to be read immediately when user presses down arrow key after reading "Alfreds Futterkiste"?

Please find the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button>Click</button>
<table tabindex="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste<p>Nice to test</p></td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not able to test at the moment, but my best guess would be because you have a tabindex=0 on the table element. Is there a reason for this? tabindex is used to tell the user that there is an interactive element (such as a link). Tables do not typically need a tabindex specified as a user can use keyboard commands to reach the table. 
Does removing the tabindex fix the issue?

Comment: I am using tabindex on table so that the user knows he is pointing to a table and can then use the keyboard commands to enter the table layer and read it. Without tabindex, the focus does not come to the table. How can a user read the table content then?

Comment: The user will know they're pointing to a table because the screen reader will inform them. It is not expected behaviour to tab to focus on a table. The keyboard commands depend on the screenreader, but in most versions of JAWS, the Insert+spacebar then the T key will allow the user to access the table layer, then there are a variety of keyboard commands that they will use to navigate the table. see: http://www.freedomscientific.com/Training/Surfs-Up/Table_Reading_Commands.htm

Comment: Thanks. I have removed tabindex but still the issue exists,

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `tabindex` attribute from the `table` tag.